# why numbers moved out of my Seaborn heatmap?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, jupyter, seaborn, heatmap

```
sns.heatmap(metric, annot=True ,fmt='g', cmap ="Blues")
plt.title('Confusion matrix')
plt.ylabel('Actual label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
```

I'm trying to plot my heatmap, but my numbers look very ugly!
[image]

Comment: `ax = sns.heatmap()` and `ax.set_ylim(2.0, 0)` worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried corr on dataset? something as follows

```
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),cmap='coolwarm',annot=True)
```